# Бот не реагирует на команды

Tags: python, discord, бот

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send("слушаю")

@bot.event
async def on_messages(message):
    if ("<@554571713354924033>" in message.content):
        await message.channel.send('пдуокгпнгщцгу')
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def Алё(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x05F505)
    embed.add_field(name=" имя ", value="текст")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def Irgaet_v():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game("игра"))

@bot.command()
async def бан(ctx):
    await ctx.send('текст ')
    await ctx.send('10%')
    await ctx.send('17%')
    await ctx.send('20%')
    await ctx.send('37%')
    await ctx.send('47%')
    await ctx.send('65%')
    await ctx.send('82%')
    await ctx.send('98%')
    await ctx.send('100%')
    await ctx.send('текст')









  
bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Когда его пингуют он отвечает, но всё что начинается с префикса он игнорирует

P.s пока писал решил его проверить , теперь он даже на пинг не отвечает , хотя я код не менял , вообще беспонятия что делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас выключены `Presence Intents`, но помимо них я рекомендую включить и `Server Member Intents` для дальнейшего взаимодействия с ботом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]